# how to open a new file in an existing Vim window from the terminal

Tags: vim

I would like to type in a terminal:

```
openInVim file.txt
```

And it will open the file in my vim unique instance

For example if I type:

```
openInVim file1.txt
# do some stuff
openInVim file2.txt
```

I want to have one vim open with the two files load

How can I do that?

EDIT :
I don't want open two files at the same time from the terminal 
I want to open a file in a single instance of vim from multiple terminal

Comment: thank you. +1 for you :)

Comment: @sebnukem you too! Sorry for my English :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated question** - how to open a new file in an existing Vim window from the terminal (if i understand correctly).

Use the `--remote` option:

```
$ gvim file1.txt
$ gvim --remote file2.txt
```

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_in_already_running_vim_from_elsewhere for details.

---

**Original question** - Here's how you open 2 files from the terminal in a single Vim window (I'm assuming here that "openInVim" is actually the `vim` or `gvim` command).

Open 2 files in 2 buffers:

```
openInVim file1.txt file2.txt
```

Open 2 files in 2 tabs:

```
openInVim -p file1.txt file2.txt
```

Open 2 files in split window:

```
openInVim -o file1.txt file2.txt
```

Open 2 files in vertically split window:

```
openInVim -O file1.txt file2.txt
```

and of course, all of this works with more than 2 files.

Answer (score 3):

Use Option `--remote` to open file in existing gvim session and `+split` for splitting screen of vim. Example:

```
gvim first_file
gvim --remote +split first_file
```

Taken from [this webpage](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_in_already_running_vim_from_elsewhere)

Or you can open it directly from gvim by `:e <path/to/file>` which close current file and open new file. Or `:sp <path/to/file>` or `:vs <path/to/file>` can be used to split screen horizontally/vertically